# A simple jQuery plugin to open a modal window

Tags: jquery

Please, I need help.

I am new to jQuery and I have link which on click should open a modal window of some sort (I want to be able to controll the position of it).

This is a simple window. It only contains some text and I want it to have just a closing button. That is all.

How can I do this in jQuery? I want something **very simple**, without to much dependencies.

Thank you all.

Comment: What have you got so far, code-wise?

Comment: Also, you could download and read the code for the jqModal plugin, which does what you're talking about - though, it may be slightly more complex than what you're proposing: http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/

Answer (score 2):

[jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/home) has its own [Dialog Plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), having the ability to be [Modal](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) and positioned explicitly from its configuration.

Answer (score 2):

try http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

there are more options on the top of this page: http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really simple [Modal Plugin](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/) for jQuery.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can try [facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox), [lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) but the simplest is [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/)